# How to write good test cases for filters in Grid?

Tags: testcase, grid

[image]
[image]

How to group test cases for filters in Grid? There are few filters options: dx popup with ranges and dx filters menu with list of parameters.
How to do this on high level instead of describe every column and every filter option.

Comment: write test case with searching combinations, first search with each single field, then write for test case for searching with combination of fields..

Answer (score 1):

Initially start writing test cases with single filter with all the condition like 
1. Exact match
2. Like with

Next start with a combination of fields in positive and negative condition with all combinations of filters in the grid.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding It is look like some charts or report related application page.

Try with following approach :

**1. Make BVT / Smoke scenarios :**

- First determine the smoke scenarios (which **configuration is mostly used by client** )
- Ask help from **Domain specific person / Product Owner / Experience tester** in same product.
- Make some test cases with **only check single value in all the filters**.

**2. Write test case related to only one component :**

- Most of time development team use **single code or component for all** type of filter and other common development.
- So just make **single test case** which check only any one component with **all scenarios**.

**3. Use tool for test case generation :**

- **Use following tool** to generate category based testcases. [Test Case Generation](https://testcasegenerator.codeplex.com/)
- Here test case cover **each and every single scenario** with all fields and all values as well.

**4. Use automation :**

- After some extent of testing it would be **very tedious task** to check all scenarios.
- So **automate this scenarios** for less risk of any component.